# How can we get weekly and monthly returns based on daily stock closing prices? All my data is in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

My dataframe originally looks like this.

```
            index ticker   Adj Close
Date                                
2022-01-03  0      AXP    166.056259
2022-01-04  1      AXP    171.387100
2022-01-05  2      AXP    169.560791
2022-01-06  3      AXP    171.114563
2022-01-07  4      AXP    172.579315
```

Or, if I reset the index, it looks like this.

```
        Date ticker   Adj Close
0 2022-01-03  AXP    166.056229
1 2022-01-04  AXP    171.387100
2 2022-01-05  AXP    169.560791
3 2022-01-06  AXP    171.114563
4 2022-01-07  AXP    172.579300
```

I have closing prices for 30 stocks, and the shape of the DF is (1769, 3). I can easily get returns and mean returns:

```
returns = table.pct_change()
mean_returns = returns.mean()
```

What's the easiest way to get weekly and monthly returns? There must be some kind of df.groupby 'W' or 'M', then returns are automatically calculated, but when I Googled it, I didn't find a whole lot. Any thoughts on how to get this working for weeks and months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the month and the week as separate columns as below, and then you can use groupby with aggregates first and last which will allow you to compute the gain for the whole week (in case you hold the stock)

```
import random
import pandas as pd

value = random.sample(range(1, 80), 79)
begin_date = '2019-10-16'

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': value,
                   'ticker':'tst',
                   'date':pd.date_range(begin_date, periods=len(value))})

df['year'] = df['date'].dt.isocalendar().year
df['week'] = df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month

weekly_increase = df.groupby(['year', 'week']).agg(['first','last'])
weekly_increase['increase'] = (weekly_increase[('value','last')] - weekly_increase[('value','first')]) / weekly_increase[('value','first')]

print(weekly_increase)
```

Results in

```
          value      ticker            date            month        increase
          first last  first last      first       last first last           
year week                                                                   
2019 42       5   59    tst  tst 2019-10-16 2019-10-20    10   10  10.800000
     43      79    3    tst  tst 2019-10-21 2019-10-27    10   10  -0.962025
     44      58   26    tst  tst 2019-10-28 2019-11-03    10   11  -0.551724
     45      70   31    tst  tst 2019-11-04 2019-11-10    11   11  -0.557143
     46      78   62    tst  tst 2019-11-11 2019-11-17    11   11  -0.205128
```

Comment: IS it like this?

weekly_gains = weekly_mean['sum'].pct_change()
monthly_gains = monthly_mean['sum'].pct_change()

Or, is it like this?

weekly_gains = weekly_mean['month'].pct_change()
monthly_gains = monthly_mean['week'].pct_change()

Comment: What do you consider a "weekly gain"? I do not view the weekly gain connection with the mean of of the gains in that week, as - for example - when holding the stock for a week, the weekly gain is "(last_price - first_price)/ first_price". But maybe you consider other cases, in which case you have to explain ...

Comment: Yeah, gain is (last_price - first_price)/ first_price. I don't have a field named 'sum' in the dataframe. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: I edited the answer to solve for what I understand you want, which is the potential gain in each period. I would say let's leave the mean out as for example a 50% (gain) followed by a -50% (loss) in two consecutive periods is not a 0 gain overall (ex: if value is 1, 1.5, 0.75 then 50% gain followed by 50% loss is in fact a 25% loss and not a 0 gain).